# How do I run CURL on a facebook group without getting the error: "SSL certificate problemq: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am trying to build a crawler for Facebook groups, and I came to a point that when running this to get the page content:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/theGroupId/";

    $ch = curl_init($url);                              // initialize the CURL library in my PHP script so we can later work on it - inside the handler. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // curl_setopt() function is used to set options on the $ch handler.// in this case we use the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);                //  "run all the stuff we've set" - return the data scraped to the variable $curl_scraped_page

    var_dump($curl_scraped_page);
    if ($curl_scraped_page === false) {
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

I get this error: "SSL certificate problemq: unable to get local issuer certificate".

I ran accross this tutorial: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/ which explains why this is happening, and how to solve it with 2 different ways, I tried both but still get the same error message:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/{theGroupId}/";

    $ch = curl_init($url);                              // initialize the CURL library in my PHP script so we can later work on it - inside the handler. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // curl_setopt() function is used to set options on the $ch handler.// in this case we use the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/GTECyberTrustGlobalRoot.crt");


    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);                //  "run all the stuff we've set" - return the data scraped to the variable $curl_scraped_page

    var_dump($curl_scraped_page);
    if ($curl_scraped_page === false) {
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }


    curl_close($ch);



    echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

This is the exact output(with the var_dump):

```
boolean false
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this the right way to do this anyway?

Comment: you can 1. ignore the certificates or 2. use the proper CA cert file that can identify the issuer of facebook certificate

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.facebook.com/groups/4189052132/";
function curl($url) {
  $options = Array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,   
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8", 
    CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $session
);
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $data;   
}   
$scraped_page = curl($url);
echo $scraped_page;
?>
```

There is no need to verify their certificate. That is why you are getting the issue.